# IIS Sites are not listed

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2012

I have an IIS server installed on EC2 instance(Win server 2012). There are 5 sites running each on different ports. Some of them are http sites and 1 is an ftp site. Every 3 days, when Application Pool or Sites is clicked, it loads and loads and never stops. The http sites also become unreachable. Once the instance is stopped and started, IIS works fine.

Can someone tell me how to permanently fix this issue?

Comment: Give this part a more detailed explanation please. "Every 3 days, when Application Pool or Sites is clicked, it loads and loads and never stops. The http sites also become unreachable." Any CPU/memory usage monitoring? Hang dump analysis? If a server reboot can help, usually it means your sites are problematic themselves (memory leak and so on).

Comment: This sounds a bit like a problem we had after the July patch day. Make sure you have all available patches installed as Microsoft fixed this problem in a later patch.

Comment: I stopped all the sites, restarted IIS and then started each site and after this IIS has not been unreachable. Thanks for the answers!